# Edit line after a pattern match but only after pattern match

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file containing multiple macros and their corresponding details.  The code of interest is here:

```
MACRO QWERTY
  CLASS FOO ;
  ORIGIN 0.0 0.0 ;
  FOREIGN QWERTY 0.0 0.0 ;
  SIZE 2.123 BY 0.369 ;
  SYMMETRY Y ;
```

I am interested in editing the SYMMETRY of *just* the macro "QWERTY" and changing it from "SYMMETRY Y ;" to "SYMMETRY X Y ;".  (G)awk or sed will work just fine.  I tried the following, but it returned emptiness:

```
gawk '1;/MACRO QWERTY/{c=5}c&&!--c{gsub(/Y/,"X Y")}'
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '/^MACRO QWERTY$/,/SYMMETRY/s/SYMMETRY Y/SYMMETRY X Y/' file
```

Output:

```
MACRO QWERTY
  CLASS FOO ;
  ORIGIN 0.0 0.0 ;
  FOREIGN QWERTY 0.0 0.0 ;
  SIZE 2.123 BY 0.369 ;
  SYMMETRY X Y ;
```